# Reactive form - position input control based on condition

Tags: html, css, angular

I have an Angular reactive form where I have a left panel and a right panel. I want to display the "Age" input control on the left panel in a certain condition and move it to the left panel in a different condition. Should I have the same input control twice in both the panels and do a *ngIf to show/hide depending on the condition or is there a better approach?

Comment: You might have to do that, or toggle a CSS rule (via *ngIf of course) to move the input around if your design is fluid.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have no choice to duplicate your input html yes, but you can share the same FormControl object between the 2 inputs, your inputs will always be synchronized.

```js
age = new FormControl(42);
```

```html
<input placeholder="age 1" [formControl]="age"/>

...

<input placeholder="age 2" [formControl]="age"/>
```